Modern .NET - Self installing a Windows Service
I have a (Windows only) .NET 8 application and I want to run it as a Windows Service.
I want my application to be able to install itself as a service when run from the console. How do I do it?
After this tldr; a bit of context.
With good 'ol .NET Framework, we had InstallUtil.exe, and the corresponding System.Configuration.Install classes (ServiceInstaller) used to run the installation / uninstall by yourself.
This was nice and easy.
Enter modern .NET, and a service could now be a daemon on other systems. Microsoft now recommends to build Windows Services with the BackgroundService infrastructure, and use a very nice and easy service installer (which I don't want to use, because my software is not installed that way), with plenty of tutorials on how to run a wizard to build an external installer (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service-with-installer?tabs=wix). This is not a solution, for me, because I want my software to run (as it is already doing) as both a Console and a Service application.
And, I want to initially run the application as a console app during initial configuration, and later install as a service after the initial configuration.
I used to use the excellent TopShelf Open Source library (https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) which would allow me to host, install and uninstall the service inside my own process, but the project has been abandoned recently.
I could use PowerShell's New-Service or sc.exe and hack my way for the main configurations, but this is for corporate environments and I need a robust and stable implementation: PowerShell is slowly updating and every now and then breaks some argument combination previously working, while sc.exe is obviously stable, but the old command line management is tricky to get right.
I'm thinking I'm going to need to fork TopShelf and extract the installation/uninstallation bits, but I would like spending my time in other activities.
Any ideas?

Where did you get the idea that powershell or sc.exe are for "corporate environments"?

In fact sc is the demonstrated approach in the Tutorial on creating a Windows Service.

Thanks Damien, but I do not understand this comments. What I wrote is that I need a robust and stable implementation. Automating sc.exe via .NET code seems to be prone to errors in encoding/escaping and various command line pitfalls. Using Powershell automation is prone to API slight changes, and different versions could require slightly different parameters. A tutorial showing interactive use is only a small bit of what I need: a robust installer embedded in my .NET application.

You can use what Microsoft recommends and run as a console and/or as a service. Just test for Environment.UserInteractive in program.cs to detect you've been ran as a console app and start your service implementation "manually". Not sure exactly what your problems are.

@SimonMourier the problem is not making a program that can run both in interactive console or as a service. That is well understood and already implemented. I want (for my program) a command line switch like --install and have my program to install itself as a service. My problem is in self installation. The way Microsoft recommends is useless, in my case, as I explained in my question.

Why do you think New-Service or sc.exe is a hack or useless? It's the official toolset provided by microsoft to do this kind of things. What hinders you from executing a a process like sc create FooService ... when someone calls your application with the --install commandline switch?

@derpirscher I don't think that neither is a hack or useless. I could use them, but I need to expose many of the options of New-Service and sc.exe to my users. Calling a single command and authoring only 1 command string is a thing, making sure that every usage of the command is correct means to test and undestand all the various escaping, double quotes, single quotes, mapping of system account, etc. Wrapping a significant amount of New-Service in a robust way is non trivial. I'm not saying that the tools are not robust. I'm saying my code using them would not be.

Even after trying various options, I use two batch files as follow.
Install.bat
sc create MyService binpath= c:\MyService\MyService.exe start=auto
sc start MyService

Uninstall.bat
sc stop MyService
sc delete MyService

I use this in build script.
What you can do is issue similar commands using Process.Start for sc and pass remaining arguments for install, uninstall.

Process.Start("sc", new string[] {
    "create",
    "MyService",
    "binpath=" + selfPath,
    "start=auto"
});



This is the kind of automation I was describing in the question, but handling the various logins, path escaping, parameter passing, etc. would be quite tricky

I awarded the bounty to this answer because it is the only one. I suppose the real answer is that there is nothing currently that covers the specific requirements I have. I think I really need to fork Topshelf... sigh.

@AlbertoChiesa, thanks, couldn't you customize Process.Start in your own code to customize options you needed?
